# Vue: how to pass a variable name as argument?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a method to load download JSON files and assign the contents to a dynamic variable. I thought this should work, but varA and varB remain empty:

```
  data() {
    return {
      varA: Array,
      varB: Array
    }
  },

  mounted(){
    this.loadJSON("example.com/fileA.json", this.varA);
    this.loadJSON("example.com/fileB.json", this.varB);
  },

  methods: {
    loadJSON(uri, target) {
      fetch(uri)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((out) => {
          target = out;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
  }
```

I've also tried to define varA and varB as computed properties, but that had the same result. How can can I do that without having to hardcode the variable names in `loadJSON()`?

Comment: but how/when are you setting up `this.varA` and `this.varB`?

Comment: your function looks fine if we are talking about passing arguments, I think the problem is where you define this.varA and this.varB

Comment: the variables are defined the normal way, in the same component, see the updated examples.

Comment: You're passing your vars as the uri argument in you function and target is undefined.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include the uri argument in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vue.set` instead:

```
  mounted(){
    this.loadJSON("varA");
    this.loadJSON("varB");
  },

  methods: {
    loadJSON(uri, targetName) {
      const self = this;
      fetch(uri)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((out) => {
          Vue.set(self, targetName, out);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
  }
```

Comment: No need to create `self` variable if you are using arrow functions. Just access `this`